# HEVC Disabling Rate Distortion Optimization in the HM Reference code

Tags: video, video-encoding, hevc, h.265

I'm using HEVC HM reference code version 10. My task is to disable the RDO of the HEVC reference encoder. For doing this i have tried to set **RDOQ** and **RDOQTS** to 0 in the configuration file, however it didn't help as the PSNR and file size before and after performing the changes remained the same. Any tip/answer to do the same will be really helpful to me. So please help if you can. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please note that RDOQ is not rate distortion optimization in general, it is a rd-based quantization control only. RDO cannot be completely disabled in HM because there is no other mode decision algorithm implemented.

Answer (score 1):

I encoded two sequences using the parameters below

```
$ ./TAppEncoderStatic -c ../cfg/encoder_lowdelay_main.cfg --InputFile=t1.yuv --BitstreamFile=slask.bin --ReconFile=slask.yuv --SourceWidth=832 --SourceHeight=480 --QP=29 --InputBitDepth=8 --FrameSkip=0 --FramesToBeEncoded=4 --FrameRate=30

$ ./TAppEncoderStatic -c ../cfg/encoder_lowdelay_main.cfg --InputFile=t1.yuv --BitstreamFile=slask.bin --ReconFile=slask.yuv --SourceWidth=832 --SourceHeight=480 --QP=29 --InputBitDepth=8 --FrameSkip=0 --FramesToBeEncoded=4 --FrameRate=30 --RDOQ=0 --RDOQTS=0
```

The difference is shown in the image below

[image: hevc]

As you can see, the rate-distortion parameters are working for me (tm)

I'm using commit `a3598fcb9d0cbf16f7594f59b18c4a25ed23df6b` from the git-mirror on

```
git://hevc.kw.bbc.co.uk/git/jctvc-hm.git
```

Hope it helps...

Comment: Thanks for your reply. One thing i wanted to know is how do i conclude that RDO is turned on or off?? My requirement is i should generate a stream in which RDO is disabled.

Comment: AFAIK there isn't any flag in the generated bitstream to indicate this. Can check the standard tonight but I think you done what you can.

Comment: @ Fredrik Phil: Thanks for your efforts. Pls do check my another question in HEVC section and try to provide some solution. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hey Zax finally how did you Toggle RDOQ Functionality in HM Code...could you please help me, I am also into the same path